# How can I stop wp_update_post messing up HTML example code?

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-update-post, characters, htmlspecialchars-decode

I'm showing little pieces of example HTML/PHP code on the frontend (with syntax highlighting). The entries are displayed as FAQ custom posts, and have a plugin (CMS Tree page) to alter the menu order, at which these are displayed. Whenever I change the order, it calls a `wp_update_post`, updating `ID`, `menu_order`, `post_parent`, `post_type`. For debug, I output the `post_content` property right before updating, and right after, and it gets changed in a horrible way.

Before (correct):

```
[html light="true"]&lt;/body&gt;[/html]
```

After (messy):

```
[html light="true"]&amp;lt;/body&amp;gt;[/html]
```

If I do it a couple of times it'll become living hell to revert:

```
[html light="true"]&amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;gt;[/html]
```

It looks exactly like `htmlspecialchars()` with `ENT_NOQUOTES` has been cast on it...

Please note that these are from the "source code" view and not the frontend. The browsers correctly handle the "Before" state, and render it as

```
</body>
```

How can I prevent it going messy?

Answer (score 1):

It was https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ plugin's fault. There are some functions in it that have something to do with this, namely `encode_shortcode_contents_slashed_noquickedit`, `encode_shortcode_contents_callback`.

Now I replaced it to https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/ but by the time I confirmed it was the other plugin's fault I had already written a solution.

```
function wpse190396_insert_post_data($data, $postarr){
    if($postarr['filter'] == 'db'
        && ($data['post_type'] == 'fix' || $data['post_type'] == 'faq')
        && (strpos($data['post_content'],'&amp;lt;') !== false
            || strpos($data['post_content'],'&amp;nbsp;') !== false
            || strpos($data['post_content'],'&amp;gt;') !== false
            )){
        $data['post_content'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($data['post_content']);
    }
    return $data;
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse190396_insert_post_data', 10, 2 );
```